# Using preg_replace on words from file not working

Tags: php, preg-replace

Here is my source

```
 $Message = $_GET["message"];
 $Username = htmlspecialchars($_GET["username"]);
 $unix = ($_GET["time"]);
 include 'mcheck.php'; 
$file1 = file_get_contents('filter.txt');
$bad_words = explode(PHP_EOL, $file1);
$compare = explode('', $Message);
foreach ($bad_words as $bad_word)
  $Message = preg_replace('/\b('.$bad_word.')\b/i', "***", $Message);
  echo $Message;
```

Say the bad word is `go`

and `$Message = I Like to go to school`

I want it to `echo I Like to *** to school`

but instead im getting

```
***I***Like***To******to***school***
```

i dont know what the problem is

Comment: Well, here's your [example](http://codepad.org/nMu3uBhl) and it works quite ok, so I think your `$bad_words` are not what you think of them. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file most likely ends with a newline (which is a good thing: all text-files on *nix systems are supposed to), which means that the last element of `explode(PHP_EOL, $file1)` is empty (it's everything between the last newline and the end of the file, which is nothing). I would recommend writing:

```
$file1 = trim(file_get_contents('filter.txt'));
```

using [the `trim` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to eliminate that last newline.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the output, you likely have an empty element in your array. So it's ultimately matching a word boundary (`\b`).

To confirm this add the following to debug your code:

```
$bad_words = explode(PHP_EOL, $file1);
print_r($bad_words);
```

As an aside, it's a waste to loop over each *bad word*. I suggest using a single regex with alterations once you've resolved the above.

For example:

```
\b(one|two|three)\b
```

Comment: So its matching the word boundry?, I dont want it to pick up words that have go in it, like lego.

Comment: The word boundary is fine, it's the empty capture that's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use `str_replace`

Example

```
$badWords = array("go","school");
$message = " I like to go to school" ;
$newMessage = str_replace($badWords, "***", $message);
echo $newMessage ;
```

Output

```
 I like to *** to ***
```

Comment: Yes, and it will replace both 'go', 'gone' and 'arsegole'. `preg_replace` was used for a reason there.

Comment: Exactly @raina77ow. Run with: `$message = 'He goes to school';`. Don't try this at home kids. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think yo need to remove empty fields from explode resulting array

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strtr` for this purpose.

you can pass  array with key=>replace, which will be somewhat more efficient that preg_replace

apart from that, must be bad badwords dic.

Comment: As noted, `strtr` would match *go*, *goes*, *gone*, etc. Hence the regex.

Comment: given you need to replace BAD WORDS  that is not necessarily a bad case ;) but agreed on regex.